# mongodb boolean value stores as a string

Tags: javascript, mongodb

```
var myobj= { school: true, address: false };     
var myArray = [];
        
myArray.push(myobj);

 updateSchool(myArray);

function updateSchool(thisSchool) {
  $.ajax
    ({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/update_school',
    data: {
        school: thisSchool, 
    },
   }
   })
```

in App.js:

```
app.post('/update_school', function(request, response) {
   ......
    dbo.collection("School").updateOne({_id: request.session.username},{$set: 
    {School:request.body.school}}, function(err, result){
    ...... }
    }
```

In mongodb boolean values stores as a string like `[{school:"true", address:"false"}]`

Could anyone help me how to store as a Boolean values in mongodb. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using mongoose? In that case, how is your schema?

Comment: I don't use mongoose. so no schema.

Comment: through nodejs save this into mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass an object to in `$.ajax()` `data`, it will be converted to URL encoded string (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) which doesn't recognize boolean data type. From the [doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> When data is an object, jQuery generates the data string from the
> object's key/value pairs unless the processData option is set to
> false. For example, { a: "bc", d: "e,f" } is converted to the string
> "a=bc&d=e%2Cf"

So in order to have the boolean saved properly you need to parse it manually in the server or send the payload as JSON (`application/json`). This is how to do the latter in jquery:

```js
function writeObj(obj) {
  document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 4) + '</pre>');
}

function updateSchool(thisSchool) {
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      // url: '/update_school',
      url: 'https://httpbin.org/anything',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify({
        school: thisSchool,
      }),
    })
    .done(writeObj)
    .fail(writeObj);
}

var myobj = {
  school: true,
  address: false
};
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(myobj);
updateSchool(myArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. As you mentioned I send data with JSON.stringify and in app.js I use JSON.parse(request,body.school)

Comment: Nice. That could work too. Although, if you are using `express`, you can use `app.use(express.json())` to automatically parse json in request body to object http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json

Comment: yes i am using express. thank you again for this tip : )